# java web app cant access linux file system

Tags: java, linux, filesystems

Trying to access file system from java web app, situation is user uploads an image and then image is ftped to another place for storage.I'm stuck on how to access the file after the upload it, i'm using the tomahawk lib for the upload which leaves me with a byte[] object after the upload so i need to convert the bytes to an image file and then ftp..this is where i get stuck.
I couldn  get the part with (new File..) to work.

In Windows i just put (C:\darksouls.jpg) and it works fine.On linux keep getting this error:

```
    javax.imageio.IIOException
```

Can't read input file?  I even tried creating an images folder in the web app and when i explode my jar the folder is there, ...

```
    byte[] imageInByte;
    BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/images/darksouls.jpg"));
```

Comment: it could be a problem with access rights on that folder.

Comment: Are you sure you mean /images and not just images? i.e. in the current directory, not the root...?

Comment: its looking like a permissions issue, now i use this: File file = new File("/home/tradeug/public_html/images/car.jpg");... i get this error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/tradeug/public_html/images/car.jpg (Permission denied), i've tried chmod 666 on the folder and the file but i keep getting the same error

Comment: you were right Eugene it was an access rights issue, as a linux noob there a few things I was missing, for one didn't know the execute bit had to be set, didn't realize the app run as user 'glassfish' which didn't have permission on that directory....

Answer (score 0):

OpenJDK does not have a native JPEG encoder , i hope this should  be the prob,try with sun's jdk ,correct me if 'm wrong